# Speeding up LINQ queries (selecting data from table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have written a code which looks like this:

```
using(var ctx = new myentitiesContext())
{
   var currentLoggedUser = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Email==User.Identity.Name);
   var items = ctx.Items.Where(x=>x.Sales>0 && x.UserId==currentLoggedUser.UserId).ToList();
}
```

As you can see it's a simple select from the DB. But the tricky part is that sometimes I can select a large quantity of data (50-100k records at a time). So what I've been wondering, are there any ways to tweak the LINQ to perform faster when the data is being pulled out of the table?

I've already created indexes in my table on FK UserId, so that part is done.

My question here is, is there any way to speed up LINQ queries via some tweaks in context configuration section, or perhaps by creating compiled queries, or via some other method ?

P.S. guys, would something like this work good:

```
ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

  // my queries...

  ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Comment: There's various ways to tell EF to take some shortcuts, such as your `AutoDetectChanges` flag and `.AsNoTracking()`, but the absolute best way to speed up your query is to avoid calling `.ToList()` until you need an actual list of all elements in memory (after any filters have been run).

Comment: @Scott The .AsNoTracking is an extension method of my object context ?

Comment: What's the primary key for `Users`? It could well be that you can save some time if you use `Find` instead of `FirstOrDefault`; I'd also recommend caching the primary key value against your user's identity too, to prevent constantly looking it up.

Comment: @Clint when you say caching , you mean by storing the value into the session ?

Comment: @User987 yes. Ideally against the Identity object itself (you can derive from `GenericIdentity` to implement your own values)

Comment: @Clint great thanks i'll look into that option... What about compiled queries in this case ,would this help as well ?

Comment: @User987 I've actually never used the compiled queries stuff, but I wouldn't have thought it would offer too much of a boost, but it all depends on your own profiling and what works for you. I'd recommend perhaps looking into them, and then maybe opening a new SO question/s to address any issues you have with them :)

Comment: Unless your DB server is fairly slow, I would not think compiled queries (or a stored procedure) would be much help. A `Select` would help minimize the network traffic if you don't need all fields, however.

Comment: An FK is worthless in this context, an Index would be the performance increaser in the scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition with the things that the rest of the users have written. You could disable lazy loading. That way if the Items Db Table has references to other tables they will not get loaded along with the Items unless you absolutely need it. Check these links

1. [thecodegarden](https://thecodegarden.net/entity-framework-best-practices/)
2. [mehdi](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

One more think that i would recommend is that you must log the sql queries that your linq expressions create and try to optimise them with your DBA. You could do this by adding an `Action<string>` delegate on the `DbContext.Database.Log` that will emit everything between a `connection.Open()` and a `connection.Close()`. You could also take the sql query out of your `IQueryable`or `IQueryable<T>` calling the `.ToString()` method on your `IQueryable` variable.

Answer (score -2):

You should make projection first. For example, this:

```
var items = ctx.Items.Where(x=>x.Sales>0 && x.UserId==currentLoggedUser.UserId).ToList();
```

will be better if you write it like this:

```
var items = ctx.Items.Where(x.UserId==currentLoggedUser.UserId).Where(x2=>x2.Sales>0 ).ToList();
```

And if you don't need all the object you have to use the "Select" clause before the "Where" and project just the properties that you need to minimize the cost, like this:

```
ctx.Items.Select(e=>new {e.UserID,e.Sales}).Where(x.UserId==currentLoggedUser.UserId).Where(x2=>x2.Sales>0 ).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually when talking to a database none of that matters.